# Swift generate CSV with comma

Tags: ios, swift, csv

I am generating CSV using below format code, It is working fine but if my text has comma its creating another empty column in csv, is there anyway to generate CSV with comma?

```
var csvText = "Name,type,\n"

for value in array {
    let newLine = "\(value.name), \(value.type)"
    csvText.append(contentsOf: newLine)
}
     
let path = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: NSTemporaryDirectory()).appendingPathComponent("Report.csv")

do {
    try csvText.write(to: path!, atomically: true, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8)
} catch {
    print("\(error)")
}
```

Comment: You need to replace that string comma with space or question mark...not sure it will help you or not

Comment: You have an extra comma in your first string.